# JavaScript array of objects get duplicates by values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects:

```
var allApps = [
    { 
        App: "Google", 
        Descr: "searching", 
        ExpiryDate: "2026-03-04T00:00:00" 
    },
    { 
        App: "Facebook", 
        Descr: "social network", 
        ExpiryDate: "2021-02-07T00:00:00" 
    },
    { 
        App: "Amazon", 
        Descr: "sales", 
        ExpiryDate: "2024-04-09T00:00:00" 
    },
    { 
        App: "Google", 
        Descr: "maps", 
        ExpiryDate: "2026-03-04T00:00:00" 
    },
    { 
        App: "Amazon", 
        Descr: "notebooks", 
        ExpiryDate: "2024-04-09T00:00:00" 
    },
    { 
        App: "Google", 
        Descr: "video", 
        ExpiryDate: "2055-03-04T00:00:00" 
    },
    { 
        App: "Google", 
        Descr: "maps and social", 
        ExpiryDate: "2026-03-04T00:00:00" 
    },
    { 
        App: "Amazon", 
        Descr: "notebooks", 
        ExpiryDate: "2035-04-09T00:00:00" 
    },
    { 
        App: "Amazon", 
        Descr: "mp3", 
        ExpiryDate: "2035-04-09T00:00:00" 
    }
];
```

I would like to receive a multidimensional array of objects where each element(array) contains the objects, where values "App" and "ExpiryDate" should be identical to each other, but values "Descr" may be different or equals. Each array must contain at least two elements:

```
var appsFiltered = [
    [
        { 
            App: "Google", 
            Descr: "searching", 
            ExpiryDate: "2026-03-04T00:00:00" 
        },
        { 
            App: "Google", 
            Descr: "maps", 
            ExpiryDate: "2026-03-04T00:00:00" 
        },
        { 
            App: "Google", 
            Descr: "maps and social", 
            ExpiryDate: "2026-03-04T00:00:00" 
        }
    ],
    [
        { 
            App: "Amazon", 
            Descr: "sales", 
            ExpiryDate: "2024-04-09T00:00:00" 
        },
        { 
            App: "Amazon", 
            Descr: "notebooks", 
            ExpiryDate: "2024-04-09T00:00:00" 
        }
    ],
    [
        { 
            App: "Amazon", 
            Descr: "notebooks", 
            ExpiryDate: "2035-04-09T00:00:00" 
        },
        { 
            App: "Amazon", 
            Descr: "mp3", 
            ExpiryDate: "2035-04-09T00:00:00" 
        }
    ]
];
```

How I can do it?
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? What strategy do *you think* you should take? Show you've made some effort.

Comment: Create an array for each app, push each app into the relevant array and then push the arrays into the parent array.

Comment: What happens when "App" and "ExpiryDate" are _not_ identical to each other?

Comment: Andy, if are not identical - ignore, not include in array appsFiltered. I want to receive the list of duplicates by values "App" and "ExpiryDate".

Comment: @Kantauver Can you show an example, how you would like to see data ? Such as like this `[[{},{}],[{},{}]]` ? Give an example.

Comment: Matt Burland, I trying to use lodash: _.uniqBy(allApps, function (elem) { return [elem.App, elem.ExpiryDate].join(); }); But in this mode I can only remove those elements that interested me, instead to get them.

Comment: @7urkm3n yes, exactly. Like array "appsFiltered" in example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a couple of `reduce` functions.

```
function mergeByHash(p, c) {

  // create a unique key from the App and
  // ExpiryDate properties
  var key = [c.App, '#', c.ExpiryDate].join('');

  // Create a new array if the key doesn't exist
  // otherwise push the object to the array
  p[key] = p[key] || [];
  p[key].push(c);
  return p;
}

function moreThanOne(p, c) {

  // if the array of the hashed property has
  // more than one element add it to the final array
  if (tmp[c].length > 1) p.push(tmp[c]);
  return p;
}

var tmp = allApps.reduce(mergeByHash, {});
var out = Object.keys(tmp).reduce(moreThanOne, []);
```

OUTPUT

```
[
  [
    {
      "App": "Google",
      "Descr": "searching",
      "ExpiryDate": "2026-03-04T00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "App": "Google",
      "Descr": "maps",
      "ExpiryDate": "2026-03-04T00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "App": "Google",
      "Descr": "maps and social",
      "ExpiryDate": "2026-03-04T00:00:00"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "App": "Amazon",
      "Descr": "sales",
      "ExpiryDate": "2024-04-09T00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "App": "Amazon",
      "Descr": "notebooks",
      "ExpiryDate": "2024-04-09T00:00:00"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "App": "Amazon",
      "Descr": "notebooks",
      "ExpiryDate": "2035-04-09T00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "App": "Amazon",
      "Descr": "mp3",
      "ExpiryDate": "2035-04-09T00:00:00"
    }
  ]
]
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/96yLtj55/)

Answer (score 0):

You need a double loop to filter out your items.

```
var i, j, filteredIndexes = [], foundItems, appsFiltered = [];
for(i = 0; i < allApps.length; i++)
{
    if (filteredIndexes.indexOf(i) < 0)
    {
      item = allApps[i];
      foundItems = [item];
      for(j = 0; j < allApps.length; j++)
      {
        if (allApps[j].App === item.App && allApps[j].ExpiryDate === item.ExpiryDate)
        {
          foundItems[foundItems.length] = allApps[j];
          filteredIndexes[filteredIndexes.length] = j;
        }
      }
      appsFiltered[appsFiltered.length] = foundItems;
    }
}
console.log(appsFiltered);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a proposal with one loop and a temporary object for the reference to the result array.

```js
var allApps = [{ App: "Google", Descr: "searching", ExpiryDate: "2026-03-04T00:00:00" }, { App: "Facebook", Descr: "social network", ExpiryDate: "2021-02-07T00:00:00" }, { App: "Amazon", Descr: "sales", ExpiryDate: "2024-04-09T00:00:00" }, { App: "Google", Descr: "maps", ExpiryDate: "2026-03-04T00:00:00" }, { App: "Amazon", Descr: "notebooks", ExpiryDate: "2024-04-09T00:00:00" }, { App: "Google", Descr: "video", ExpiryDate: "2055-03-04T00:00:00" }, { App: "Google", Descr: "maps and social", ExpiryDate: "2026-03-04T00:00:00" }, { App: "Amazon", Descr: "notebooks", ExpiryDate: "2035-04-09T00:00:00" }, { App: "Amazon", Descr: "mp3", ExpiryDate: "2035-04-09T00:00:00" }],
    result = [];

allApps.forEach(function (a) {
    var k = a.App + '|' + a.ExpiryDate;
    if (!(k in this)) {
        this[k] = [];
        result.push(this[k]);
    }
    this[k].push(a);
}, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```